# Filtering: Filtering Generate an array of Presidents that served more than 4 years and that were not Democrats

Tags: javascript, if-statement, filtering

[The Exercise and Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoPXI.png)

function mapPresidents(person) {

```
var freshList = {
  id: person.id,
  number: person.president,
  firstName: person.nm[0],
  party: person.pp,
  yearsInOffice: officeYears,
};

let years = person.tm.split("-");

let officeYears= 0

if(years.length > 1){
  officeYears = toNumber(years[1]) - toNumber(years[0])
  console.log(officeYears);
}

return freshList;
```

}

var newPresidents = presidents.map(mapPresidents);

function filterPresidents(person) {
let result = false;

```
if() {

}

return result;
```

}

**I am having trouble with the logic that should be fed into my if statement to complete the filter.**

"Generate an array of Presidents that served more than 4 years and that were not Democrats"

Comment: (1) Don't post JavaScript (object literals) as image. Enter & format as text; (2) *"I am having trouble"* is not a suitable "question" for Stack Overflow. Please provide your attempt, code, traces of research, what is going wrong with your attempt (error, wrong output, ...Etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, in your `map()` you are forgetting to update your `freshList` object with the updated `yearsInOffice`  variable once you've calculated `officeYears`

Your filter function will only return items that match the condition, `person.officeYears >= 4 && person.party.toLowerCase() != 'democrat'`. You can set it up the same way you did the map() only, use `filter()`

I would present code in the answer, but as this is a homework assignment or something like it, you will get more value from finishing that part yourself.

Comment: Thank you, I think I got it. Will post it and maybe you can take a look at it for me?

Comment: Ok. First you want to filter on newPresidents -  `var newListPresidents = newPresidents.filter(filterPresidents)`

Comment: second, rather than adding an answer to your own question (which is frowned upon unless it's an answer that you came up with independently from anyone elses) you can set up a codepen or plunkr or the like and share the link for this kind of thing

Comment: Yes, I think I am good. My bad on the posting, I am fairly new at stackoverflow! Thank you very much.

Comment: @johnny -  Excellent!  If this answer helped solve your question, please accept it as the solution by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. Cheers!